# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP time zone configuration and Helm chart

Tags: java, sql, kubernetes, timezone, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to change CURRENT_TIMESTAMP time zone in database. In database, timestamp column is set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at default. Database is running at UTC, but I want it to be EST or America/New York. I am using helm chart to configure my project, and I would like to use it to configure the time zone of my database. I am thinking something like this:

```yaml
...
    env:
      - name: TZ
      - value: 'America/New_York'
...
```

How can I configure helm chart in order for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in my database to use certain time zone in spring boot?

EDIT: my helm chart looks something like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myProject
  namespace: {{ .Values.base.namespace.shared }}
  labels:
    app: myProject
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myProject
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.myPorject.autoscaling.minReplicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myProject
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myProject
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
...
...
...
```

Comment: Why would you not want your database to be in UTC?  UTC is guaranteed not to change in the future.

Comment: it is business related. we use EST in timestamp to calculate user preferred time. So I need to send EST timestamp not UTC.

Comment: which specific chart you use? There are implementations like [Add ability to modify timezone](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/7123), but hard to reply you without additional info

Comment: @Vitalii hmm.. im new to helm chart.. is kubernetes-helm chart good enough specification? I will update my post.

Comment: In general, it is almost certainly more appropriate to store values in UTC and convert them to EST when you get them out than to store them in EST.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you on real example.
I am using [stable/mysql](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/mysql) chart for that.

To be able to fetch `stable` charts it is [required](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6359#issuecomment-554765526) to add `helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/` prior to helm usage

As per [mysql helm chart documentation](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/mysql) you have `timezone` parameter to [modify](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/7123/commits/4ddd0cf53f69f6074f2bc27d0a05ef740124aa6f) during or before installation, depends on method you chose.

You can set parameters installation, using `helm install --name my-mysql --set timezone='America/New_York'`

Either you can fetch helm chart, modify parameter and deploy chart.

```
helm fetch --untar stable/mysql
$ ls mysql
Chart.yaml  README.md  templates  values.yaml
```

values.yaml will contain next section for edit

```
## Populates the 'TZ' system timezone environment variable
## ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html
##
## Default: nil (mysql will use image's default timezone, normally UTC)
## Example: 'Australia/Sydney'
# timezone:
```

But still think twice..I fully agree with Wasserman's last comment re converting values